# How to do fuzzy string matching between dictionary and dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, fuzzywuzzy

I have a dictionary like this

```
Station                    Latitude        Longitude
London Bridge            51.50467435      -0.086005598
Kings Cross              51.53079819      -0.122756421
Kings Cross St. Pancras  51.53031246      -0.12387213
Euston Square            51.52866433      -0.133296472
Leicester Square         51.51129118      -0.128242148
Russell Square           51.52301304      -0.124590198
Sloane Square            51.49235976      -0.156488857
...
```

And I want to match ['ORIGIN'] and ['DESTINATION'] column in df with the dictionary, and get their coordinates.

df:

```
  ORIGIN                DESTINATION              origin_coor     destination_coor  
  St. Pancras           london bridge/farringdon
  London' Kings Cross      Euston Sq
  ...
```

The ideal outcome would be:

```
  ORIGIN                    DESTINATION            origin_coor     destination_coor  
 St. Pancras      london bridge/farringdon    (51.53031246,-0.12387213) (51.50467435,-0.086005598)
 London's Kings Cross      Euston Sq       (51.53079819,-0.122756421) (51.52866433,-0.133296472)
          ...
```

My code is as below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ORIGIN': ['Kings Cross St. Pancras', 'Kings Cross'],
                   'DESTINATION': ['London Bridge', 'Euston Square']})

geo = {'London Bridge':(51.50467435, -0.086005598),
       'Euston Square':(51.53031246, -0.12387213),
       'Kings Cross':(51.49235976, -0.124590198),
       'Kings Cross St. Pancras':(51.52301304, -0.086005598)
      }

df['origin_coor'] = df['ORIGIN'].map(geo)
df['destination_coor'] = df['DESTINATION'].map(geo)

df
```

But the question is there are discrepancies between the place names in my dictionary and dataframe, so I cannot simply use map function. Does anyone has a solution?

Comment: 1. That is not a dictionary 2. How did you create the dataframe? I do not see one. 3. It is not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You can use `.str.contains()` with a regex for fuzzy matching, but it looks like your data is dirty enough that it won't work well. You may need to clean up your data prior to the analysis you want to do.

Comment: [Jellyfish](https://jellyfish.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) has some common fuzzy matching metrics, if you're more interested in fuzzy matching than focusing on data cleaning